# sybase to sql serve using alchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: image is incompatible with varchar(max) (206) (
```

I am trying to load data from sybase to sql server.
One of the column seem to hold images. It throws above error
Can I use any other option

here is code i use

```
  sql = "select picture,id from noose" --- fetch data from sybase
  df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn) --- load data 2 dataframe
  print(df)
  df.to_sql('xx', con=sql_engine, schema='dbo', if_exists="replace",  index=False) ---- load to sql server
```

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/839

Comment: @GordThompson mate do you know how can I convert this column in hex value than?

Comment: Well, you could call `str()` on it and get a string representation with Python-style encoding: `str(bytes([x for x in range(16)]))` produces `"b'\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05\\x06\\x07\\x08\\t\\n\\x0b\\x0c\\r\\x0e\\x0f'"`. Not very efficient, though.

Comment: @GordThompson i want it like 0001020304